# Scala.js: CSS styled console logs

Tags: javascript, scala.js

With javascript I can print styled logs on the console like e.g. this:

```
console.log('%c Oh my heavens! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
```

which will result in:

[image: styled console log]

Is there any way I can do the same using Scala.js? The standard `println` does not seem to have this functionality.

*Edit: Of course one could always use `scala.scalajs.js.eval` for such cases but I'd prefer a more "scala native" way:

```
js.eval("""
 console.log('%c Oh my heavens! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
 """)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `console.log` using, for example, the dynamically typed API:

```scala
js.Dynamic.global.console.log("%c Oh my heavens!",
    "background: #222; color: #bada55")
```

Comment: Nice. Works as expected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

[scala-js-dom project](http://scala-js.github.io/scala-js-dom/) provides type safe bindings for this and most other browser features:

```
import org.scalajs.dom

dom.console.log("%c Oh my heavens! ", "background: #222; color: #bada55")
```

No need to use `js.Dynamic`